# swfobject and Mouserdown Event

Tags: javascript, swfobject, addeventlistener, onmousedown, mousedown

I am trying to find a way to know when a user clicks on a swfobject.
I tried `flashMovie.addEventListener("mousedown", onPlayerMouseDown, false);` but it works only on Mac OS and not on Windows/Linux.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the Flash source you can add a listener to the stage and then make an ExternalInterface call back to your javascript:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSEDOWN,MoseDownHandler);

function mouseDownHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(ExternalInterface.available) ExternalInterface.call("someJavascriptFunction");
}
```